# Counterexample of pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

For the counterexample mentioned here, it emphasizes that the theorem needs compactness. But in this case, even if we take the compact set $[0,1]$, the convergence is still not uniform right? (I'm not sure, but is the sequence of functions not pointwise convergence at $1$?)

Comment: I don't understand what is the question here. In order to apply the theorem, one needs all of (a), (b) and (c). One thus cannot simply expect one has uniform convergence by simply changing $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: In General Topology by R. Engelking this is called The Dini Theorem. (Ch, 3, Section 3.2, Prop, 3,2,18....page 143.... He writes $R^X$ for the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R.$) He gives the same proof, albeit a bit briefer.

Comment: every compact set is closed and bounded so (0,1) is not compact. on the other hand [0,1] is compact but function f (limit function is not continuous in 0) so both of them do not provide required conditions and so they may not be uniform convergent which is the case here (The function sequence is only ponitwise convergent)

Answer (score 1):

No the convergence is still not uniform, but the theorem doesn't apply to this situation.

If you expanded the $f_n$ defined in Rudin's counterexample to all have domain $[0,1]$, then although the sequence $f_1 \geqslant f_2 \geqslant \cdots $ still converges pointwise and monotonically on a compact set to some function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, this limit function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in (0,1] \\ 1, & x = 0 \end{cases}$ is not *continuous*, so we can't use the theorem to deduce uniform convergence (part $(b)$ is not satisfied, so the theorem doesn't apply).

If the theorem can't be used, how can we answer whether or not this sequence of $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly? Well, if it did, then the sequence in the restricted sense, where each $f_n:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, would have to converge uniformly to the zero function. Rudin straight tells you this is not true: if $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $(0,1)$ then there would exist some $N$ after which indices $n \geqslant N$ satisfy

$\forall x \in (0,1), \,\,|f_n(x)| < \frac{1}{2}$.

But letting $n := N \geqslant N$ and $\tilde{x} := \frac{1}{N} \in (0,1)$ we have $|f_n(\tilde{x})| = \frac{1}{2}$, contrary to our choice of $N$

Answer (score 1):

Let the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be defined such that $f_n(x)=1-x^{\frac{1}{n}}$. This is a montonic decreasing function that is pointwise convergent however isn't uniformly convergent. Since the interval $[0,1]$ is compact this implies that the following conditions aren't sufficient for uniform convergence.

The key here is that it converges to a **Continuous** function.

While the sequence functions in your example converges to a continuous function in $(0,1)$ it doesn't do so in $[0,1)$ as 
$$f:[0,1)\to \mathbb R\:| f= \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &\mathrm{if}& x=0\\
0 &\mathrm{o.w.}
\end{array}\right.$$

which is the same in my example aswell.

Comment: {(-1,1),(-2,2),(-3,3),(-4,4),(-5,5),...} is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ with no finite subcover. ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky right going to fix that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|f_n-f\|_K=\sup \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:x\in K\}.$ Then $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly, on $K$, to f  iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n-f\|_K=0.$

Suppose $K$ is a subspace of $L.$  If $(f_n)_n$ does not converge uniformly ,on $K$, to $f,$ then $\|f-f_n\|_K$ doesn't converge to $0$, so $\|f-f_n\|_L$ doesn't converge to $0$ either , because $\|f-f_n\|_L\geq |f-f_n\|_K.$

In your Q,  the "problematic" point is $0$. Another essential need of the theorem  (besides compactness of $K$) is that $f$ is continuous. $(f_n)_n$ converges point-wise monotonic-decreasing to $f$  on $[0,1]$, but $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$ because $f(0)=1$ but $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (0,1].$